# If I am enrolled in Bachelor's degree taught in English, Can I in the future continue with Master's Degree taught in different language?

Tags: masters, degree, bachelor

Is it possible?, do Universities recognize the knowledge you have and believe in your billingual skills in the field that you are studying, or is it completely not being acknowledged, and require you to retake the degree in the language you want to get Master's degree as if you were without the degree in the first place?

Comment: Is the master's in the same degree field as the bachelor's?

Comment: Yes, Computer Science, to be exact! @Philly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to repeat the degree. Just as non-English-speaking students can do graduate studies in the US after passing the Test of English as a Foreign Language (TOEFL), other countries also have language proficiency exams. For example, [Germany](https://www.studying-in-germany.org/proof-of-language-proficiency-german-english/) has the "Test Deutsch als Fremdsprache" (TDAF). When you apply for your master's degree, they may require this test or something else (e.g., an interview) to prove your fluency.

The more subtle point is that not all degrees are interchangeable. As my answer in [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138775/how-to-pursue-an-md-phd-in-france-after-bs-from-the-us/138782#138782) question points out, there may be a whole procedure to verify that your degree is compatible with the foreign one. This is unlikely to be an issue if you go to a reputable English-language school, but you may want to do further research before committing to this.

Comment: sure, but If I'm currently studying Computer Science at an Undergraduate level in UK, there shouldn't be any problem with going for Master's in Computer Science at a German University  then?

Comment: As I said, I think it is unlikely to be an issue, particularly if the country is Germany and the field is computer science [though, you will find that my guarantee counts for absolutely nothing :-) ]. Since your question was quite broad, I tried to make my answer equally broad. If your field were medicine or social work, or you were planning to go to a non-Western country, I could imagine things being much stickier.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make the question not completely narrowed to my case, but as you've already pointed out - I made it quite a bit too broad in the process!

Comment: Computing in German is, in my experience, pretty close to English. I was once told, in Germany by a native speaker of German, that "die Datenbank wird upgedated."

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are specifically studying something really English related, such as English Literature, there is no reason that language matters at all. Math is the same in Britain as it is in Spain. It isn't an issue.

But even if you were studying, for example, the foundations underlying the English language, there is no reason you couldn't do something similar for German or Swahili.

In the US, also, there is a fairly clear break between undergraduate and graduate education. Interesting changes of field are possible. Other places it might be a bit more constrained due to tighter integration of the degrees.

Comment: So if I am currently Studying for Computer Science Bachelor's degree  in English, there shouldn't be a problem when I graduate and choose to go for Master's in Computer Science degree taught in German at some German University? - Sure I will need the proof of my German language skills, but not the things strictly related to my Bachelor's degree?

Comment: Correct. But note that it might be difficult to gain admission for other reasons. The German system is quite different from the US, for example. It might be closer in some ways to UK. You don't say where you are studying now. Moreover, most German academics are pretty fluent in English, though the coursework probably won't be.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I was really anxious about it, but not anymore, Thanks!